# Update all components after System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on"); was changed to "off"

Tags: java, swing, system-properties

Is it possible to update for example all `JTextField` components in existing application to show rendered text (or not rendered) while setting and later changing system properties? All `JTextField` components are initiated just once.

System properties are set like that:

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");
//Now we need to change system property
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "off");
//After repaint(); - no changes (it takes effect if application is restarted only)
```

Comment: I "think" you might be forced to recreate the native peer to force a change the underlying `Graphics` context.  You'd have to `dispose` of the active window and then make it visible again, but I've not tested that theory

Comment: `dispose()` and then `setVisible()` did not helped..

Comment: out of luck for current JVM instance, there should be a brutte_force, but cant be applied to whole (already) visible GUI

Comment: So I switched to "must restart the application" option..